# Confused about sequence function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am confused about which statement is true about a query in SQL Server as I have posted below:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Number_Sequence 
AS TINYINT
   START WITH 2
   INCREMENT BY 3
   MAXVALUE 9
```

Which of the following is true about the `Number_Sequence` shown here?

1. This sequence can generate infinite values
2. This sequence can generate only 3 values at the maximum
3. This sequence can generate only 4 values at the maximum
4. For this sequence, by default `MINVALUE` will be set to 0
5. For this sequence, `INCREMENT` cannot be negative

Comment: You made no effort. You can easily read the documentation and try this yourself - which would be a far better approach to learning.

Answer (score 0):

The `CREATE SEQUENCE` call completes and the sequence object is created. Now you can fetch the next value from the sequence:

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR number_sequence
```

returns: 2

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR number_sequence
```

returns: 5

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR number_sequence
```

returns: 8

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR number_sequence
```

Throws error:

> **Msg 11728, Level 16, State 1, Line 7**
>   The sequence object 'Number_Sequence' has reached its minimum or maximum value. Restart the sequence object to allow new values to be generated.

So your sequence can generate exactly **3** values - 2, 5, and 8 - and then it's "done" and cannot be used anymore.....

Answer (score 0):

**Correct Answer is 2. This sequence can generate only 3 values at the maximum**

Try with following code in SQL server

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Number_Sequence 
AS TINYINT
   START WITH 2
   INCREMENT BY 3
   MAXVALUE 9


   SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR number_sequence

   SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR number_sequence

   SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR number_sequence

  -- SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR number_sequence
```

It will show 2,5 and 8

[image]

If you call 4th time following queriy

```
 SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR number_sequence
```

It will give you error

```
Msg 11728, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
The sequence object 'Number_Sequence' has reached its minimum or maximum value. Restart the sequence object to allow new values to be generated.
```